# Set state inside async function using stateless React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a simple react form, for which I have an async function used on the "onBlur" event of one of the fields. I wanted to check an info in the backend and then update some fields based on the response.

The thing is that setting the states are behaving really strange. It seems sometimes it populates it, and sometimes not. Do I need to do something "special" to set states in an async function?

```
async function handleEmailBlur(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
. . .
                        const {id} = data[0]
                        let toSave = data[0]
                        delete toSave.id
                        const toSaveC = toSave

                        console.log("===> To Save")
                        console.log(toSave)

                        setId(id)
                        setRecoveredData({...toSaveC})

                        console.log("===> Recovered Data")
                        console.log(recoveredData)
. . . 
}
```

In this example, although `toSaveC` has data, with the same field names, `RecoveredData` shows no data in the end.

Comment: You are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) log it outside the handleEmailBlur function and it'll be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because react update state  asynchronously, use `useEffect` hook to check state change like this:

```
useEffect(()=>console.log(recoveredData),[recoveredData])
```

this effect will fire when `recoveredData` change.

Comment: Great, tks! I wasn't sure this was the correct way to do that!!